# Validation in jquery ,

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="default-box">
    <span class="add"><input type="text" class="name" /><input type="text"  class="email"/></span>
    <span class="add"><input type="text" class="name" /><input type="text"  class="email"/></span>
    <span class="add"><input type="text" class="name" /><input type="text"  class="email"/></span>
```

There is a button to submit.

```
validation:
```

`1.` On these three row if any row is filled it is OK, if all three row is empty then it is invalid.

`2.` While writing emails if it is wrong it validates on loosing focus.

Comment: To clarify -- if ANY input has data, it's ok. If ALL inputs are blank, it's not? If name and/or email is filled in, the the respective name/email must also be filled in? Do you want to validate anything past "content exists"? Valid* email, for example? *it's really hard to validate email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You should at least give it a try.  Post your code.  Here is a head start. This will loop through the inputs.

```
var $inputs = $('input');
for(var i = 0; i <= $inputs.length; ++i) {
   if($inputs[i].val() != "") 
    return true;
}
```